# What's the difference in Structured Streaming from Spark 2.2 to 2.3?

Tags: spark-streaming

I see in the release notes of Spark 2.3 the announcement/unveiling of Structured Streaming, but I know it's been around for a while. Due to some dependencies, I need to use Spark 2.2 in a system implementation, but I also want to start moving batch-oriented work into a streaming paradigm.

Is there anything significant I'm missing in not having Spark 2.3, or was that just the release where Structured Streaming became "official" instead of experimental?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to talk to someone "in the know" at a local meetup, and his (slightly off-the-record) response was that you could use the structured streaming in 2.2, but you shouldn't be surprised if the results were less-than-stable (i.e. buggy) if you tried to use in a production environment.

He furthermore suggested that even Spark 2.3 had some situations where certain edge cases could easy cause problems, and that there were a lot of fixes along the way that should make it more stable for 2.4. So the note to myself is that I should try to use this in production until my various other dependencies allow for Spark 2.4. A pity, because I think this new approach is wickedly elegant.